# Remove question mark "?" from file names OSX

Tags: macos, unix

My music library contains many .flac files that need the "?" removed from the filename as my current music player (Sonos) cannot for some reason see those files.

Is there a command or script that would help me find & remove question marks "?" in my music directory?

Directory setup:

```
~/music/artist/album/01 title with?.flac
```

Thank you

Comment: This isn't the best answer, since it's possible to write a script to do this, but if you have a bit of extra cash, check out A Better Finder Rename: http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/

Comment: Thank you Eric that seems like a pretty good program I will bookmark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal and change to your directory, then use the command listed to remove all occurrences of `?` within your filenames in that directory:

```
cd ~/music/artist/album/

for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f//\?/}"; done
```

***Before you commit*** to runing the command you can test it, which will show you the original filename followed by new one:

```
for f in *; do echo -- "$f" "${f//\?/}"; done

-- 01 title with?.flac 01 title with.flac
```

To do this recursively you'll need to use the `find` command, and **definitely try it in a test directory first**. Messing up on the replacement strings of all your filenames could make things far worse than better. For recursive operations such as this I always recommend backing up your data beforehand.

The first command is the dry run, meaning nothing is actually changed.
The second command is the real thing, which recursively renames all filenames (eliminating question marks) in the current directory *and all sub-directories*:

```
find . -type f -name '*\?*' | while read f; do echo mv "$f" "${f//\?/}"; done

find . -type f -name '*\?*' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f//\?/}"; done
```

Comment: l'L'l, can this be applied to all the directories within ~/music? As it stands now, I will have to navigate to each album's directory and run this command. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is VERY cool!  That's in the `bash` shell, I assume?

Comment: @spacecat, I've updated the answer to reflect with an additional command to recursively rename your files.

Comment: @Eric, — indeed it is (+ bash shell) :)